# Find out location of extern variable at linking time

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I'm working on a fairly large project which I didn't start, and which has multiple redefinitions of the same variables for different architectures, compilers, etc. I have to modify (add functions to some header files), following the template of those already there (which are declared as extern). I'm wondering if there's a way to find out where these extern functions are linked to (so where they're defined) when I run GCC? That would be amazing!

thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't `grep` solve your problem? Say if the function is `type name(...)` you grep for `"type name("` and you'll get all declarations and definitions.

Comment: unfornunately there's so many functions with that same name (read, write) and i'm struggling to find out which one refers to...

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/). It builds 'index' of your code and helps to find any symbols on it. Also cscope can be configured to work with vim/emacs.

Comment: Thanks this is definitely a brilliant start